# Can't see tables while importing database

Tags: mysql, sql, database, import

Why can't I see tables while I am importing database in phpmyadmin. It shows me success but then still I am not able to see any tables. Though if I run any query it does show me the result. What is the problem? I have tried finding answers online but couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is unanswered. Sorry had to write.

Answer (score 0):

Try clicking on another database to see if it refreshes. Also check the file config.inc.php to see if you tables are being hidden. Search for a line similar to

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['hide_db'] = 'your-db-name';

Comment: No, it not not refresing. Neither there is this line in the config.ini.php file.

Answer (score 0):

Are you in the correct database? You can use

```
show databases
```

to find out all databases in your MySQL.
And you can use

```
SELECT DATABASE()
```

to find out your current database.

I am thinking you might have the database tables created in one database that is not your default database.

Hope this helps.